# pipe not found. Pipe is working with typed value like 'some string' but not working with dynamic value(value from ts file)

Tags: angular

I want to titlecase value in angular template, My template is this and this is working fine without any pipe:

```
<h5 class="user-info__job"> {{ userDetails.working }} </h5>
```

This works fine, but as soon I apply titlecase pipe like this:

```
<h5 class="user-info__job"> {{ userDetails.working | titlecase }} </h5>
```

It throws error pipe could not be found:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq9qk.png)

I tried the following code:

```
<h5 class="user-info__job"> {{ 'Some typed value' | titlecase }} </h5>
```

And this was working which means everything is imported i.e CommonModule is imported, I don't know whats wrong. I am initializing value in component as follow:

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit { 
    userDetails: RegisterUserModel;

    constructor(private mainsiteService: MainSiteService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.userDetails = this.mainsiteService.userDetails;
    }
}
```

My angular version is 9.

Comment: Can you share the interface or class for `RegisterUserModel`

Comment: you need import the BrowserModule in your main.app.module: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` or the CommonModule`import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'` if your component is in a lazy-module (and don't forget add in **imports**)